# Partial decoding of ByteStrings to Text

Tags: haskell, text, decode, bytestring

I need to decode ByteStrings from various encodings into Text, but the ByteStrings might be incomplete fragments. Ideally, I would need a function with signature of something like:

```
decodeFragment :: Encoding -> ByteString -> (Text, ByteString)
```

which returnes the succesfully decoded Text as well as any remaining bytes that didn't form a complete unicode character (so I can re-use those bytes when I get the next fragment).

Does this sort of function already exist in some Haskell library, or do I need to roll my own? For now, I could even get started with something that doesn't support encodings beyond UTF-8.

Comment: Have you searched http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tricky. Usually, [encoding](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/encoding) is my go-to suggestion for encoding and decoding text, but I don't believe it offers the exact thing you're asking for. It comes close, in that it offers

```
decodeChar :: (Encoding enc, ByteSource m) => enc -> m Char
```

which you can iterate to get a `m String`. Catching the errors thrown by `decodeChar` will tell you if you've come to the end of a fragment. A cursory look at some of the other encoding packages on Hackage suggests that they will either require the same approach or will require a patch to expose the function analogous to the above one that they use internally.

Comment: Getting an `m String` doesn't sound very good for getting `Text`.

Comment: It's about the best Hackage has to offer at the moment.